# REST API query to get all accounts which have child records?

Tags: soql, rest-api

```
/services/data/v26.0/query?q=select+a.Id,+(select+c.Id,+c.FirstName,+c.GUID__c,+c.LastName,+c.Middle_Name__c,+c.Phone,+c.Email,+c.Professional_Role__c,+c.HCP__c+from+Contacts+c)+from+Account+a +where+a.Contacts!=null
```

I am using this i am running into error of no field found named contacts.

How will i get only those accounts with corresponding contacts which have atleast one contact.

I want to eliminate all those accounts that has no contacts .Please note i want to do it in a single REST API call.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about this?

**Only Accounts with Contacts**

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Email FROM Contacts)
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact)
```

The subquery in SELECT optional of course (do you want the contacts returned too or not?)

**Only Accounts that have no Contacts**

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Account
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact)
```

Comment: Thank you.Appreciate quick response and perfect answer.Wish i had one more vote to vote.

Comment: No probs, it took me a while too before I discovered how to us it too (hard to search for it if you don't know proper keyword). It's "anti joins" in the official docs: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm

Comment: Ya correct.Always getting different perspective to a problem helps it to solve quicker and this site is awesome .Isn't it?

Comment: +1 - as using inner queries in criteria is least known feature of SOQL